# Moving IBM MQ away from mainframe - best practice?

Tags: ibm-mq

Today we have our MQ installations primarely on mainframe, but are considering moving them to Windows or Linux instead.
We have three queue managers (qmgrs) in most environments. Two in a queue sharing group across two LPARs, and a stand-alone qmgr for applications that doesn't need to run 24/7. We have many smaller applications, which shares the few qmgrs.

When I read up on building qmgrs in Windows and Linux, I get the impression that most designs favor a qmgr or a cluster per application. Is it a no-go to build a general purpose qmgr for a hundred small applications on Windows/Linux?

I have considered a Multi instance Qmgr (active/passive) or a clustered solution.
What is considered best practice in a scenario, where I have several hundred different applications that needs MQ communication.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you are asking for an opinion that is not allowed on StackOverflow.

Secondly, if you have z/OS (mainframe) applications using MQ then you cannot move MQ off the mainframe because there is no client-mode connectivity for mainframe applications.  What I mean is that the mainframe MQ applications cannot connect in client mode to a queue manager running on a distributed platform (i.e. Linux, Windows, etc.).  You will need to have queue managers on both mainframe and distributed platforms to allow messages to flow between the platforms.  So, your title of "*Moving IBM MQ away from mainframe*" is a no go unless ***ALL*** mainframe MQ applications are moving off the mainframe too.

> I get the impression that most designs favor a qmgr or a cluster per
> application.

I don't know where you read that but it sounds like information from the 90's.  Normally, you should only isolate a queue manager if you have a very good reason.

> I have considered a Multi instance Qmgr (active/passive) or a
> clustered solution.

I think you need to read up on MQ MI and MQ clustering because they are not mutually exclusive.  MQ clustering has nothing to do with fail-over or HA (high-availability).

Here is a description of [MQ clustering](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/7.5?topic=intercommunication-how-clusters-work) from the MQ Knowledge Center.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand and  document your requirements.

**What failover time can you tolerate?**
With Shared queue on z/OS if you kill one  MQ - another MQ can continue processing the messages within seconds.  Applications will have to detect the connection is broken and reconnect.
If you go for a mid range solution, it may take longer to detect a queue manager has gone down, and for the work to switch to an alternative.  During this time the in-transit messages will not be available.

If you have 10 mid range queue managers and kill one of them, applications wich were connected to the dead queue manager can detect the outage and reconnect to a different queue manager within seconds, so new messages will have a short blip in throughput.  Applications connected to the other 9 queue managers will not be affected, so a smaller "blip" overall.

**Do you have response time criteria?**   So enterprises have a "budget" no more than 5 ms in MQ, no more than 15 ms in DB2 etc.
Will having midrange affect response time, for example is there more or less network latency between clients and servers.

**Are you worried about confidentiality of data**.  On z/OS you can have disk encryption enabled by default.

**Are you worried about security of data**, for example use of keystores, and having stash files (with the passwords of the keystore) sitting next to the keystore.  Z/OS is better than mid range in this area.

You can have tamper proof keystores on z/OS and midrange.

**Scaling**
How many distributed queue managers will you need to handle the current workload, and any growth (and any unexpected peaks).  Does this change your operational model?

**If you are using AMS**, the maintenance of keystores is challenging.  If you add one more recipient, you need to update the keystore for all userids that use the queue- on all queue managers.  With z/OS You update one key ring per queue manager.

**How would the move to midrange affect your disaster recovery**?  It may be easier (just spin up a new queue manager) with midrange, or harder - you need to create the environment before you can spin up a new queue manager.

What is the worst case environment, for example the systems you talk to - if they went down for a day. Can your queue managers hold/buffer the workload?
If you had a day's worth of data, how long would it take to drain it and send it?

**Where are your applications?** - if you have applications running on z/OS (for example , batch, CICS, IMS,  WAS) they all need a z/OS queue manager on the same LPAR.  If all the applications are not on z/OS then they can all use client mode to access MQ.

**How does security change?** (Command access, access to queues)